# Regular closed sets in a subspace of a topological space

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $\langle X,\mathscr{O}\rangle$ is a locally compact and Hausdorff topological space and $\operatorname{RC}(X)$ is its algebra of regular closed sets (i.e. these that are equal to the closure of their interior). Suppose $K\in\operatorname{RC}(X)$ is compact and consider $\langle K,\mathscr{O}(K)\rangle$, a closed and compact subspace of $X$. Must it be the case that $\operatorname{RC}(K)\subseteq\operatorname{RC}(X)$ (i.e. every set which is regular closed in $K$ is also regular closed in $X$)? What if we skip local compactness or $T_2$?